# How do I get they keys and the values from the object and return an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So let me give you an example object:

```
{
  example_98: value,
  example_7658: value,
  example_2764: value
  key: value,
  otherKey: otherValue
}
```

I want to search this object for all the `example_x` and return an array that looks something like:

```
[{example_98: value}, ...]
```

What is the easiest way to do this in Javascript? I prefer pure javascript but I do have access to jquery if that makes it easier.

Comment: @daremachine Gonna need an actual answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all of the keys of an object the following way:

```
var obj = {
  example_98: value,
  example_7658: value,
  example_2764: value
  key: value,
  otherKey: otherValue
}

console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // ['example_98', 'example_7658', ...]
```

To get all of the objects whose keys match a certain value, you can do this:

```
var regEx = /example_/;

var onlyExamples = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(function(o) {
    // only return keys that match regEx
    return o.test(regEx);
  })
  .map(function(o) {
    // return { key: value }
    return { o: obj(o) };
  });
```

This will return an array of objects with *only* those values that match the regular expression, so your example object would return `[{example_98: value }, {example_7658: value }, {example_2764: value}]`.

**Edit**

As @andlrc pointed out, you can refine your regex to to select only those keys that *start* with "example" by using: `var regEx = /^example_/;`

Comment: Might consider making that regex: `/^example_/` and use `regEx.test(o);`

Comment: Assuming `Object.keys()` is available then it's reasonable to assume that [`String.startsWith('example_')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is also available (though I've not compared the efficiency of each approach to suggest that approach is *better*, but it feels more readable).

Comment: @DavidThomas Valid point, but afaik `String.startsWith` isn't supported by IE.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way? A [`for-in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
var results = [];
for (var key in obj) {
  if (key.indexOf('example_') === 0) {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj[key] = obj[key];
    results.push(newObj);
  }
}
```

A more interesting/functional way:

```
var results = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(function(key) {
    return key.indexOf('example_') === 0;
  })
  .map(function(key) {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj[key] = obj[key];
    return newObj;
  });
```

A variant on the previous but using computed names (not available in many environments):

```
var results = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter((key) => key.indexOf('example_') === 0)
  .map((key) => { [key]: obj[key] });
```

Comment: This does not help me. I specifically stated I only want  keys and their associated value, that started with `example_`

Comment: @KyleAdams I missed that part. I'm updating it now. It's just a matter of filtering out the keys that match your criteria.

Comment: @KyleAdams Updated. Future reference, you should really edit your question to tell us *what you have tried*. Filtering results is a pretty common operation.

Comment: I didnt know what to do .